# Why use a constructor instead of directly assigning a property value?

Tags: javascript

I have a basic class which I am instantiating through my application. Coming from other OOP languages I have been taught to use constructors. However, I'm trying to determine what the advantage is in JavaScript.

Why use a constructor:

```
stateClasses.Canvas = function (name) {       
    this.name = name || 'Canvas';
    this.GUID = null;

    var _constructor = function (obj) { obj.GUID = stateFunctions.generateGUID() }(this);       
};
```

instead of directly assigning the property a value?

```
stateClasses.Canvas = function (name) {       
    this.name = name || 'Canvas';
    this.GUID = stateFunctions.generateGUID(); 
};
```

Comment: using a function to pass in initialization arguments gives you a chance to interrogate/check those initialization arguments.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't see the constructors usefulness in this case because the value being assigned by the constructor is not a a value that was passed in as an argument. So in the case where the value is an argument, I could see the usefulness in being able to act on that value before assignment.

Comment: Actually, @mmcrae that brings up another point. What about setting a property equal to an anonymous function, which takes the class argument as a parameters and then returns an appropriate value? In that case you would also be able to interrogate the value. This is where JavaScript gets weird for me. I suppose a constructor could be "cleaner" in terms of code readability.